# Creating a table using mysqli and php

Tags: mysql

The table is not created in the database `Users` and there is no error message at all. PhpMyAdmin is set to allow no password, just to be clear on that point.

```
CREATE TABLE Users(
    ID string(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName string(255) NOT NULL,
    Surname string(255) NOT NULL,
    DOB date(10) NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: does the query work if you run it directly in MySQL (e.g. via WorkBench)?

Comment: Mysql does not know "string". You will have to use "varchar". The date field does not need a defined length. You can leave that out. The create table query will work like this: `CREATE TABLE Users(
        ID varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        FirstName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        Surname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        DOB date NOT NULL
)`

Comment: Agreed with @natheriel

Comment: Thanks @ADyson for suggesting I run it separately, as it did give an error, I just didn't know what the error was.

Comment: Thanks @natheriel. That fixed it.

Comment: @natheriel I would post that as an answer, if I was you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your query should be like this.

```
$mySql = CREATE TABLE Users(
         ID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
         FirstName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
         Surname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
         DOB date NOT NULL
    )";
```

1. MySQL can't understand string. pass varchar instead of a string.
2. you don't need to assign the length of date.